# Can i use @GenericGenerator alone without @GeneratedValue?

Tags: java, hibernate

Learning java, i don't see a clear answer on this yet. Any clarification appreciated.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@JsonExclude
private String id;
```

Q1: can i use GenericGenerator alone ?

Q2: if i'm passing in "id" in my object, will @GeneratedValue still generated the new id and overwrite the passed in one ? If so, how to keep the existing id, don't call @GeneratedValue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: can i use GenericGenerator alone ?

Not really. It takes the name of a generator defined by a `@GeneratedValue`.

> Q2: if i'm passing in "id" in my object, will @GeneratedValue still generated the new id and overwrite the passed in one ? If so, how to keep the existing id, don't call @GeneratedValue ?

This depends on the underlying implementation. Usually if the object already has the ID set it is not generated again. However you should not mess with IDs yourself and you should let the `EntityManager` manage those.

When you save a new entity it will not have the `id` set, so the generator will create a new one when persisting the entity. When you query the entity from your data store it will be populated by the persistence framework (in this case hibernate). It will also track that instance for any future updates to the entity that you might want to save back.